# Obtain RuntimeMethodHandle from interface?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, expression-trees

I have a piece of dissassembled code which didn't work quite well around some reflection code. I have no idea on how to make it valid as I don't know how to work with MethodHandles etc... I think it should be a pretty simple task for a reflection guru because (as far as I can deduct) the only thing that needs to happen is 'getting a method handle from an interface'? Am I correct?

The following parameter is wrong.. IProductRepositoryItem.Code should be a RuntimeMethodHandle

```
(MethodInfo) MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(IProductRepositoryItem.Code));
```

Full code:

```
ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T), "i");
// ISSUE: method reference

Expression<Func<T, object>> property =
    Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(
        (Expression) Expression.Property(
            (Expression) Expression.Convert((Expression) parameterExpression, typeof (IProductRepositoryItem)),
            (MethodInfo) MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(IProductRepositoryItem.Code)), 
                new ParameterExpression[1] {
                     parameterExpression
                });
string key = entityHelper.GetField<T>(property);
```

Comment: I have never used `RuntimeMethodHandle` in C#. It is quite common though if you are writing a compiler.

Comment: All other questions tagged [methodhandle] seem to be about the Java feature.  Is there a C#-related tag that would be more appropriate for this question?  (I don't know C# so I'll leave it to you (anyone) to change it, if warranted.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your function has no parameters, you should change the entire offending line to this:

```
typeof(IProductRepositoryItem).GetMethod("Code");
```

If it does take parameters, use the appropriate overload of [`GetMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethod.aspx).

**EDIT**: If you're trying to access a property, you should use the overload of [`Expression.Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348662.aspx) that takes a `PropertyInfo` rather than a `MethodInfo`.

```
typeof(IProductRepositoryItem).GetProperty("Code");
```

Comment: That returns a `PropertyInfo` whilst `GetMethodFromHandle` only accepts a `RuntimeMethodHandle`.
EDIT: Whoops I'm not following your exact instructions...

Comment: @Ropstah: How can `GetMethod` return a `PropertyInfo`? Does not compute.

Comment: Code is a property, I thought I'd just change it without 'reflecting' those changes here in the question... ;)